# Understanding SUM in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

So, I thought I had a decent understanding of what the sum function is doing until today...I have a query:

```
select me.ARTICLE_NO, me.DUE_DATE, me.QTY, mv.COST

 from ARTICLE me
inner join PURCHASING pi
on pi.doc_no = me.doc_no
inner join ARTICLE_VALU mv
on me.ARTICLE_NO = mv.ARTICLE_NO
where me.flag = 'Y'
and mv.prce > 0
and me.ARTICLE_NO in ('TYH0P',
                     'H5TK11',
                     'P4156321',
                     'G54621',
                     '54689P-01',
                     '52P100-02',
                     '6JGHYK',
                     'GGDSJH-09',
                     'JHDKF-04',
                     'GH51JKF')
group by me.ARTICLE_NO, me.DUE_DATE, me.QTY, mv.COST
```

This returns the following:

[image]

So then, what I really want is the sum of qty, so I have updated the query to be the following:

```
select me.ARTICLE_NO, 
   me.DUE_DATE, 
   sum(me.QTY)
   from ARTICLE me
   inner join PURCHASING pi
   on pi.doc_no = me.doc_no
 inner join ARTICLE_VALU mv
   on me.ARTICLE_NO = mv.ARTICLE_NO
   where me.flag = 'Y'
   and mv.prce > 0
    and me.ARTICLE_NO in ('TYH0P',
                     'H5TK11',
                     'P4156321',
                     'G54621',
                     '54689P-01',
                     '52P100-02',
                     '6JGHYK',
                     'GGDSJH-09',
                     'JHDKF-04',
                     'GH51JKF')
group by me.ARTICLE_NO, me.DUE_DATE, me.QTY
```

I expected the results to become:

[image: new results]

Instead I get this:

[image]

I just have no idea why it didn't give one sum value per one ARTICLE NO, and the correct sum too as well. Per my understanding the sum is constrained by the where clause, so what I see as the dataset, before adding the sum function, I expected that sum will only work on those values in that dataset and not picking up any other data. Hopefully these screen shots made sense. I had to manually change all data and table names etc. to keep that information private.

Comment: remove groupings, then. you're grouping by 3 things. do `group by article_no` only instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `me.QTY` from `GROUP BY`

```
select 
   me.ARTICLE_NO, 
   me.DUE_DATE, 
   sum(me.QTY) AS Qty_Sum
from ARTICLE me
join PURCHASING pi
  on pi.doc_no = me.doc_no
join ARTICLE_VALU mv
  on me.ARTICLE_NO = mv.ARTICLE_NO
where me.flag = 'Y'
  and mv.prce > 0
  and me.ARTICLE_NO in ('TYH0P',
                        'H5TK11',
                        'P4156321',
                        'G54621',
                        '54689P-01',
                        '52P100-02',
                        '6JGHYK',
                        'GGDSJH-09',
                        'JHDKF-04',
                        'GH51JKF')
group by me.ARTICLE_NO,
         me.DUE_DATE;
```

**EDIT:**

You can use CTE:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  select me.ARTICLE_NO, me.DUE_DATE, me.QTY, mv.COST
  from ARTICLE me
  inner join PURCHASING pi
    on pi.doc_no = me.doc_no
  inner join ARTICLE_VALU mv
    on me.ARTICLE_NO = mv.ARTICLE_NO
  where me.flag = 'Y'
    and mv.prce > 0
    and me.ARTICLE_NO in ('TYH0P',
                     'H5TK11',
                     'P4156321',
                     'G54621',
                     '54689P-01',
                     '52P100-02',
                     '6JGHYK',
                     'GGDSJH-09',
                     'JHDKF-04',
                     'GH51JKF')
 group by me.ARTICLE_NO, me.DUE_DATE, me.QTY, mv.COST
)
SELECT 
   ARTICLE_NO, 
   DUE_DATE, 
   sum(QTY) AS Qty_Sum
FROM cte
GROUP BY
   ARTICLE_NO,
   DUE_DATE;
```

Some explanation to avoid confusion:

When you've written:

```
select me.ARTICLE_NO, me.DUE_DATE, me.QTY, mv.COST
...
group by me.ARTICLE_NO, me.DUE_DATE, me.QTY, mv.COST
```

you basically do the same as:

```
select DISTINCT me.ARTICLE_NO, me.DUE_DATE, me.QTY, mv.COST
```

Now you want to operate on this `DISTINCT` subquery to get new result. So you need to wrap it with CTE/Subquery to get result you proposed. Your attempt to adding `SUM` to initial query and change grouping will operate on different data.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. I have removed the QTY from the group by. Now I get one ARTICLE NO per line, but the QTY is still off. For example, I have: ARTICLE NO of TYH0P now have a QTY of 510, still not the 16 I expected.

Comment: SCORE!!!! that worked....I am still confused as to the need to go that route though. I guess I just don't understand sum as much as I thought I did.

Comment: @nikifi I've added expalanation for you